# How to implement SignalR using websockets

Tags: websocket, .net-core, signalr

I am trying mostly for learning purposes to implement a module similar to `SignalR`(still a beginner in `SignalR`) using raw `websockets`. (I am already very familiar with `websockets`)
Is there any guide or something that explains what functionality does `SignalR` have on top of `websockets`? (so that i know what features i need to implement) ? .

From what i understood it keeps a `persistent` connection , and can fallback to other protocols if `websockets` are not supported (long polling ...etc).

I have already checked this [video](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/videos/getting-started/signalr-and-web-sockets) but i need something more in detail.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR maybe this help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had written one article regarding SignalR one year back. It contains SignalR basic information and code example.

Following is the link of it -

https://medium.com/@aparnagadgil/real-time-web-functionality-using-signalr-ba483efcb959

Hope this helps you!